# Return every request as plain json Laravel using Middleware

Tags: laravel, nginx, laravel-6, php-7.3

I have a route in my web.php that returns a view:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
```

welcome is default Laravel view welcome.blade.php.

I have Middleware called AlwaysReturnJson and it contains:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class AlwaysReturnJson
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {

        $request->headers->set('Accept', 'application/json');
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

I set up this middleware in Kernel.php as global middleware:

```
 protected $middleware = [
        \App\Http\Middleware\AlwaysReturnJson::class
    ];
```

What I expect is to get plain text/json of welcome file in my browser when I navigate to given route but I always get it as html and it render page properly. I checked it, it applies middleware on every request so that is not a problem. Why is  this happening and shouldn't it convert that view to a plain text? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @AngadDubey no controller here. OP use closure to return view

Comment: try returning the view as json response `return response()->json([
        'welcome' => view('welcome')
    ]);`

Comment: @N.Dockic I'm trying use your way and success. I think it's not Laravel issue but webserver.

Comment: You are setting an `Accept` header, this is more like saying: "Always accept json".

Comment: @WahyuKristianto could you maybe give me direction about what problem could be with server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to set a header for your response you can do this:

```php
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class AlwaysReturnJson
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $response = $next($request);

        $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');

        return $response;
    }
}
```

If you want to force return valid json content use this middleware instead:

```php
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class AlwaysReturnJson
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $response = $next($request);

        return response()->json($response->getContent());
    }
}
```

See Laravel docs about [after middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/master/middleware#defining-middleware) for more info.

You can alternatively return `json` response on your controller without any middleware needed:

```php
Route::get('/', function () {
    return response()->json(
        view('welcome')->render()
    );
});
```

Comment: Your answer is basically correct, I will mark it as accepted answer but have you tried example that I tried like this: $request->headers->set('Accept', 'application/json');  ?
 Does it return always json for you?

Comment: @N.Djokic my first answer just sets `Content-Type` header (not `Accept`). However I've updated my answer and added a code to force your response to be a valid json.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use laravel After middleware (the middleware would perform its task after the request is handled by the application) and then set the content-type of response.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class AfterAlwaysReturnJson
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $response = $next($request);

        return $response->header('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. Have you tried my example code? Did it return json response?

Comment: I will give it a try and go back to you

Comment: I gave it a try , and YES your code works fine for me (tested on Laravel 5.7)